# How to restrict input in typeaheadbasic yii2 extension

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I am using **TypeaheadBasic::widget** extension for autocomplete but I want to restrict on inputs. I want to allow only items contained in the array.

below is my code.

```
use kartik\typeahead\TypeaheadBasic;
 echo TypeaheadBasic::widget([
      'model' => $model,
      'attribute' => 'client',
      'data' => $clientData,
      'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...', 'id'=>'client_id_name'],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                ]);
```

please give me solution. thanks advance!

Comment: view "select Repository" part .http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow the user to choose from a set of options, why not use [Select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2). This way your users can type to filter the options and just choose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution for my above question is below :

but i don't know this is the proper/standard way or not.. but its working fine for me :)

here is my view : typeheadbasic extension

```
 $clientData = $my_dynamic_data_arr; // this arr var i used in jquery script for chekcing if name is exists or not
    echo TypeaheadBasic::widget([
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'client',
                        'data' => $clientData,
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...', 'id' => 'client_profile'],
                        'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                    ]);
```

here is my jquery script to handle above problem

```
 var client_arr = $.makeArray(<?php echo json_encode(array_values($clientData)); ?>); // $clientData is php array variable from above 

    $("#clientProfileForm").submit(function(event) {
        var client_name = $("#client_profile").val();
        if ($.inArray(client_name, client_arr) === -1) {
            $("#clientProfileError").html("<spna style='color:red'>Client not exists</span>");
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#client_profile').val() === '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#clientProfileError").html("<spna style='color:red'>Client name is required</span>");
        }
    });
```